# Same album repeatedly updates when syncing iTunes with iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, sync

I have many many albums and tracks purchased via the iTunes store both through iTunes directly and via the iPhone. They all synchronise properly and are on iTunes eventually (i.e. if purcashed originally on the iPhone).

There's one album, though, purchased via the iTunes app in June this year. Virtually every time I sync the iPhone it says "updating files" and this album gets updated. The rest of the sync goes just fine, new tracks added, listened to podcasts are removed, playlists are updated (notwithstanding that smart playlists' orderings are now utterly broken) fine - but this album is always getting updated.

In finder I've looked at the permissions and nothing seems unusual. FWIW, I'm on Mac OS X 10.5.8, iPhone 3.1.2, iTunes 9.02.

Anyone with any ideas?

It's not a fundamental problem, but it does means that each sync takes an extra 30-60 seconds, which is annoying!

Answer (score 2):

This annoyed me too. I'll tell you what worked for me.

I noticed that several songs from the Roots album Phrenology always updated during a sync, along with about 20 other songs from various artists and albums. I went to the Phrenology to see if there was anything fishy about the songs. I noticed that some of the songs had the correct album artwork, and some just showed a black square (not a blank square, like a song without any artwork). So I right-clicked and copied the correct artwork into the songs' "corrupt" artwork. After selecting and playing the songs and still seeing the black square, I deleted what came up as a little black square from each of the trouble song's artwork tab of their info pane (right click song and click "Get Info."), leaving the correct album artwork as the only one. The correct artwork showed when I selected the track, ONLY those Phrenology tracks updated on the next sync, and NO tracks from NO albums from NO artists updated during the sync afterwards. Hallelujah. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this problem in the past. I seem to remember fixing it by changing some of the metadata of the album's tracks - i.e. changing the Ratings - then resyncing. It, in my case, synced the album for a final time before never seeming to happen again. Worth a try I suppose.